# Looping multiple times through class instance var not just once

Tags: python, for-loop

**Am I doing something wrong with my loops? Why is it only using the first occurrence of `fozz` and not looping through all 30+ objects of `fooz`?** Any help is really appreciated. Thanks.

I have a var `parser` which brings in a dictionary of values.

I then have a few inner `for()` loops which exchange a dictionary value, with a value from a class instance var `fooz`.

`fooz` has about 30 values.

**The problem is:** currently its only using 1 value from `fooz` when looping. I want to use each value, against each parameter for all instances of `fooz` (please see *what i'm trying to do* below)

For instance, on a path like:

```
somesite.com/id.php?date=052914&param=6&dog=cat
```

It outputs:

```
date=<same fooz object>
param=<same fooz object>
dog=<same fooz object>
```

**The loop**

```
for parsed_key, parsed_value in parser.iteritems():
    for parsed_value in parser.iteritems():
        for fooz in foozs:
            parsed_value = str(fooz)
    print parsed_key + '=' + parsed_value
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
date=<fooz object 1>
date=<fooz object 2>
date=<fooz object 3>
...
date=<fooz object 30>

param=<fooz object 1>
param=<fooz object 2>
param=<fooz object 3>
...
param=<fooz object 30>

dog=<fooz object 1>
dog=<fooz object 2>
dog=<fooz object 3>
...
dog=<fooz object 30>
```

Comment: I have not down voted you yet but your question is really unclear. I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: I dont get the downvotes either. My question really is why is my loop just occuring for the first occurance of "fozz" and then stop - when there are 30 objects from fooz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loops are wrong.

```
for parsed_key, parsed_value in parser.iteritems():
    for parsed_value in parser.iteritems():
        # You're already looping on parser.iteritems() why are you
        # trying to do that again??
        for fooz in foozs:
            parsed_value = str(fooz)
            # parsed_value has been every value of fooz, but...
    # by the time you get here you're completely out of all those for loops and
    # Python doesn't care about those inner iterations, it only gives you the
    # last one since that's the last thing you set parsed_value to
    print parsed_key + '=' + parsed_value
```

Try:

```
for parsed_key, parsed_value in parser.iteritems():
    for fooz in foozs:
        parsed_value = str(fooz)
        print parsed_key + '=' + parsed_value
```

Comment: Haha, really appreciate the comments here. I guess I got a bit loop-y() here. Thank you!

Comment: @CodeTalk in fact it's a little worse than I commented, I realize. If you're unpacking `parsed_key, parsed_value` out of `parser.iteritems()` the first time, then the second time you're setting the WHOLE TUPLE to be `str(fooz)`. I have NO idea how you're getting one of those `parsed_value`s to be a `fooz` object, except that Python2 leaks its `for` variable out of scope when the loop ends. Maybe that's it?